# Jquery load vs. hide and show

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I'm trying to replace the contents of a div when clicking a button in the menu and having looked at different options, I'm wondering what the best practices are for this.

I have a left side menu (with buttons A B C D E F and son on) that when clicked on, replace the content on the right hand side.

a) I could just have the new content hidden and shown on click jquery function. But having at least 50 content replacements to be done, I am wondering if this doesn't slow down the page load too much?

b) Or would it be best to use the jquery load function?

Any thoughts, much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: is all the content large or small? will the users show each panel?

Comment: Can all content be on the screen at once or do they replace one another? Have you looked at jQuery-UI TABS?

Comment: In general if the content is large and there is a chance that it will not be shown, then it is best to lazy load them, in order to keep the client as light as possible.

Comment: I've made a quick jsfiddle to illustrate. Actually, it's not the sidebar that triggers the event, it's a thumbnail within the container . http://jsfiddle.net/m/wkd/

Comment: That is a perfectly working example but with lots of content to be replaced, my question is whether this is a bad practice, as there will be so much hidden HTML?

Answer (score 1):

you can send an ajax request and after getting response you can set the content of the div.

```
$("#div1id").html(data);
```

Similarly you can use

```
$("#div1id1").load('/path_to_servlet');
```

Comment: Thanks! Here is my jsfiddle to illustrate the issue. jsfiddle.net/m/wkd At the moment I'm using the hide/show method, but with so much content to be shown/hidden for each thumbnail, I'm wondering if this is the best practice? I'm not too familiar with ajax so I want to keep it simple. Is there any other way or should I dive into ajax? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!

```
$(".thumbs").click(function(){
$( "#Grid" ).load('project_sample.html .project_thumb');
});
```